# More precise way to talk about "a set of representatives"

Tags: terminology

If $G$ acts on $X$, then $X$ is the disjoint union of the distinct orbits. That is, one can write
$$
X = \bigcup_{x\in R} orb_G(x)
$$
where $R$ is a set of representatives, with one element from each orbit.

It might just be me, but this feels a bit awkward. Is there another way to say this "one element from each orbit"? Is there another way to properly define $R$?

Comment: To my knowledge, the expression "set of representatives" is perfectly understandable.

Comment: [transversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(combinatorics)) or *cross-section*  are some such terms.

Comment: $R$ is a hitting set of minimum size for all orbits. This definition feels, hmm, more awkward.

Comment: Would choice function be something you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be the quotient of $X$ by the action of $G$, defined in the following way.
Define an equivalence $\sim_G$ relation on $X$ by
$$x_1\sim_G x_2 \iff \exists g\in G : x_2=g.x_1$$
and set $Y:=X/\sim_G$. (When the action is clear from context, the notation $X/G$ is also used).

For each $y\in Y$, set $O_y:= \mathrm{orb}_G(x)$ for any $x$ with $[x]=y$, where $[x]$ denotes the quotient projection (the class of $x$ in $Y$). This definition is well-posed by definition of $\sim_G$, i.e. if $x'$ is such that $[x']=y$, then $\mathrm{orb}_G(x')=\mathrm{orb}_G(x)$.

Now we have
$$X=\bigcup_Y O_y\quad.$$

In words, $Y$ replaces $R$ in that we do not need to choose one representative $x$ for each class $y=[x]$, and can rather directly choose as indexing set the set of classes. The awkwardness in using $R$ comes precisely from the arbitrariness of the choice of a representative for each class, but we in fact we do not need to make such a choice in the first place.

Comment: Of course we can write $X$ as a (disjoint) union of the (partitioning) equivalence classes. But the OP is asking how to less awkwardly do so in *representative* language, so this is not an answer to that question.

Comment: The purpose of an answer can be that to suggest an alternative way of thinking to the question. Of course one *can* write $X$ as a union indexed over a set of representatives, yet no terminological nuance will make the awkwardness of this description go away. Presenting a different, arguably more precise and canonical, way to describe $X$ (as union indexed by its quotient space) might be a polite way to suggest that using representatives may not be a good choice in the first place.